# Convergence of $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$ and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n(\log n)^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The following are two theorems regarding convergent series in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:

> [image]
>   [image]

Rudin then makes a comment

> [image]

Here are my **questions**:

- If "we continue the process", what would be the next pair of series?
- How do exercises 11b and 12b illustrate the "point"?

---

Here are the exercises mentioned above. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The next series after formula (13) is  $\sum _n[\;(n \log n)(\log \log n)(\log \log \log n)^p\;]^{-1}$, converging iff $p>1.$

Comment: The "point" is that for any positive sequence ($a_n)_n$ such that $\sum_na_n$  converges there is a positive monotone sequence $(b_n)_n$ where $\sum_nb_n$ converges with  $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n/b_n=0,$ OR $\sum_na_n$ diverges and $\sum_nb_n$ diverges  and $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n/a_n=0.$  There is no "minimal rate of convergence" of $a_n$ to $0$ that is necessary to ensure that $\sum_na_n$ converges....BTW in modern Number Theory, it is common to see formulas like $\log\log \log\log n$. One number theorist said  it goes to infinity "with great dignity."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure on 11b and 12b, but repeated applications of Cauchy's condensation test will provide an obvious pattern.  Note that:

$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac1{n\log(n)\log^p(\log(n))}<\frac1{\log(2)}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log^p(n)}<\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac2{n\log(n)\log^p(\log(n))}$$

So as you can see, it reduces to checking the convergence of the previous series.  One may extend this to series of the form

$$\sum_{n\ge k}\frac1{n\log(n)\log(\log(n))\dots\log^p(\log(\log(\dots\log(n)\dots)))}$$

Or, one could use the integral test with the substitution $u=\log(\log(\log(\dots\log(x)\dots)))$.